# React Web-App show Blank or not Rendering after add Url-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My React Web-app was ok with `wabpack` Before add `url-loader`.

But when I add `url-loader` it show blank or not Rendering anything.

[MY Project File Link with Github](https://github.com/ashikjs/react-Portfolio)

MY `webpack.config.js` Files

```
module: {

        // After add this code app show blank
        // ************************************
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|.jsx|jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/i,  // a regular expression that catches .js files
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'url-loader',

            },

       // **************************
            {
                test: /\.(js|.jsx|jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/i,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react','es2016', 'stage-0',],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
                }
            },
        ]
    },
```

**Console.log**

[image]

Comment: Does webpack show any error? Does your web explorer give any error?

Comment: @lilezek no hare no error show console ..

Comment: Why are you trying to use `url-loader` on JavaScript files? And why are you trying to using `babel-loader` on image files? Limit your `test` expressions to just the filetypes you want each loader to act on.

Comment: @JoeClay Nice Question...... but I can't load css and svg files by `babel-loader` I was made some search on google then I got the solution by `url-loader`  still I don't love `url-loader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both rules have the exact same `test` regular expression, which means that they will be applied to the same files and this causes a conflict. In your case it used `url-loader` for your JavaScript files and `url-loader` will give you a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) instead of JavaScript that could be executed.

You should not have conflicting rules and you should only match the files that are meaningful to pass through the loader. For example `babel-loader` is only for JavaScript, everything else will fail, therefore it should never be applied to anything but JavaScript.

Your rules might look likes this (I changed it to use webpack 2+ syntax, for details have a look at the [official migration guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/)).

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            // For images and fonts.
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/i,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
        },
        {
            // For JavaScript files (.js and .jsx)
            test: /\.jsx?$/i,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['react','es2016', 'stage-0',],
                plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Perfect Answer..
can you Also say me why it give error for css ??

Comment: You'll need to configure [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).

Comment: But why @Michael When I was already use `url-loader`.and why we need  extra something like `css-loader` for every thing.....
SO why we use `babel-loader` have any Felicity ??

Comment: The loaders do different things which are needed for different file types. For example [`sass-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) is transforming Sass into CSS, it is able to parse Sass syntax and translates these extra features to regular CSS, which is what the browser understands. Every loader focuses on one thing and does that well. They often leverage existing tools and it makes it easier to combine these tools with webpack. Whether you need `babel-loader` depends on whether you would need [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) (for new JavaScript features).